# Find out whether the function is differentiable at the given point.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

I have got a function:
$
f(x,y)=\tan((x^3-y^3)^{1/3}+2y)
$;
And I need to check it for differentiability at $(0,0)$.
So, here is what I have done so far:
$$
\text{By definition}\ \  
f_x'(0,0)=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{tan(\Delta x^3)^{1/3}}{\Delta x}=1
$$
$$
\text{Similarly:}\ \ 
f_y'(0,0)=\lim_{\Delta y\rightarrow 0}\frac{tan((-\Delta y^3)^{1/3}+2\Delta y)}{\Delta y}=1  
$$
$$
df=f_x'\cdot\Delta x+f_y'\cdot\Delta y=\Delta x + \Delta y
$$
$$
\Delta f(x,y)=f(x+\Delta x, y+\Delta y)-f(x,y)=f(\Delta x, \Delta y)=
df+o(\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2})
$$
Hence, the limit
$$
\lim_{(\Delta x, \Delta y)\rightarrow(0,0)}
\frac{\tan((\Delta x^3-\Delta y^3)^{1/3}+2\Delta y)-\Delta x - \Delta y}
{\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}}
$$
equals $0$ if and only if the initial function is differentiable at $(0,0)$.
The question is **how to solve this limit?**

Comment: What is the definition of $$f(0,0)$$?

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean is $$f(0,0)=0$$?

Comment: I think we should prove or disprove that.

Comment: I get $$\tan((0^3-0^3)^{1/3}-0)=0$$

Comment: Okay, but what does it have to do with the initial problem? I mean checking for differentiability.

Comment: I have deleted my post since someone give me a $-1$

Comment: That wasn't me.

Comment: You must compute $$\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}$$ and if the limit exists for $h$ tends to zero.

Comment: And $$\frac{f(0,h)-f(0,0)}{h}$$

Comment: But the limits you just wrote are the partial derivatives that I've already computed, aren't they?

Comment: Ok, you have to show that these limits exist in $P(0,0)$

Comment: I don't understand. Of course they exist because they equal $1$ and $-1$ respectively.

Comment: But they must be equal! And in your second line it must be $$\frac{\tan((-h^3)^{1/3}+2h)}{h}$$

Comment: Yes, you right. But anyway, I can't solve the last limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your limit doesn't exist. Take $x=y$ and $x=2y$ and you will get two different answers: zero and non-zero. Therefore, the given function is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.